# Setting editingStyle on custom cell in tableFooterView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, footer

The following code (located in my `-viewWillAppear`) successfully implements a cell as a tableFooterView:

```
CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:0];
    UITableViewCell *footerCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRect];
    //footerCell.editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    footerCell.textLabel.text = @"Add New Class";
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerCell;
```

However, the line that is commented out returns this error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

How can I set the editingStyle of this cell to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `UITableViewCell` instances are meant to only go into `UITableView` "rows" and not into the footer itself.  However since it is subclass of `UIView` I guess it will work.

The issue you are having is that it is a readonly property.  The information you are trying to set is normally discovered by the `UITableView` through delegates. Therefore you are trying to put a square peg into a round hole.

I would create a custom `UIView` to put into your footer instead of trying to put a `UITableViewCell` in there.

Comment: That makes sense. Darn pegs :P